# Add dependency from ppa to package

Tags: ppa, dependencies, launchpad, pygi

I'am building simple dropdown terminal emulator application with PythonGI + GTK+3.0, I am using libkeybinder3.0 and gir1.2-keybinder3.0 packages for global keybinding these packages not available in default repository, they had special ppa. I dont want to say my users here is my ppa install my application and here is another ppa for dependencies, how can i merge these packages with my project.

Can i upload these 2 packages to my apllication's ppa, because i thought launchpad dont let you mirror packages to your ppa? Or how can i link dependencies with my package so user can install only one ppa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try the following:

According to the [Launchpad's Help](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage#Depending_on_other_PPAs):

> Launchpad satisfies your package's Build-Depends using:
>
> - the most recent versions of the packages in the PPA you're uploading to
> - all sections of the primary Ubuntu archive -- i.e. main, restricted, >- universe and multiverse
> - optionally: other PPAs in Launchpad.
>
> Note: If you're already familiar with uploading to the Ubuntu primary archive, you should note that PPA builds do not have any build dependency restrictions, unlike a build in the primary Ubuntu archive. If you want to build the same package in the primary Ubuntu archive at a later point you may need to revise the package's component and/or pocket.
>
> **Depending on other PPAs
>
> If you want Launchpad to satisfy your package dependencies using one or more other PPAs, follow the Edit dependencies link on your PPA or the team's overview page.**

Hope will be helpful.

Comment: But this works just for build dependencies, not for runtime dependencies, I think?